# Lazy (dynamic) import of firebase modules triggers destructure error

Tags: javascript, firebase, import, module

The following import triggers the error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'getAuth' of '(intermediate value).default' as it is undefined.`:

`const { getAuth, signInWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider } = (await import('firebase/auth')).default;`

Is there another way I should be lazy importing these modules from Firebase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to import `.default` export iirc, try this:

```js
const { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } = await import("firebase/auth");
```

Works on version `9.0.0-beta.7`:

[image]

Comment: `getAuth` and `signInWithEmailAndPassword` both get `undefined` with this approach.

Comment: @IanDavis which version are you using? seems to be working on `9.0.0-beta.7`

Comment: I just did `npm install firebase`. Maybe I need to do something like `npm install firebase@9` ?

Comment: @IanDavis `npm install firebase` will install the older version (v8) and not the modular SDK. Older version don't have `getAuth()` and hence that's undefined. Try `npm i firebase@9.0.0-beta.7` [Get the version 9 SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#get_the_version_9_sdk)